# Why some entries are missing in Perl ENV hash

Tags: perl, shell, docker, environment

Perl is giving me an undef value when I access a variable that is supposed to be defined in the **%ENV** hash. How is this possible?

```
root@23cd5f45def7:~/bin$ perl -e 'warn $ENV{SHELL}'
Warning: something's wrong at -e line 1.
```

I would expect perl to output **/bin/bash** instead.

More info on the environment:

```
root@23cd5f45def7:~/bin$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

root@23cd5f45def7:~/bin$ $SHELL --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...

root@23cd5f45def7:~/bin$ perl -v

This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 91 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
...
```

I am running this on Debian wheezy in a docker container.

The image was created with

```
sudo debootstrap wheezy ../_build  http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian
sudo tar -C ../_build -c . | docker import - wheezy/bootstrap
```

I get the same beheviour with perl-5.24.1 compiled manually from sources.

Comment: @Jens: Works for me without the import (Perl 5.18.2).

Comment: Works on v5.10.0 without import

Comment: What output do you get from `perl -E 'say for keys %ENV'`?

Comment: Enable warnings with `-w`.  I think you will see that `$ENV{SHELL}` is undefined.

Comment: @Thilo: Works on many perls for me as well, including perl-5.14.2, except for the one scenario I described in the question. I'm guessing something perl takes for granted is missing in the bootstrapped Debian image or there is some weirdness going on related to docker.

Comment: @JRFerguson. We already know it is undefined. The question is why? It should be placed in the $ENV hash.

Comment: @Håkon Only 7 entries (way fewer than 'set' shows in /bin/bash):
HOME
SHLVL
HOSTNAME
PWD
TERM
_
PAT

Comment: @AndrewDwojc: I would guess that it hasn't been exported for some reason. Does it help if you `export SHELL` before running the perl command? It's possible that there's a `typeset +x SHELL` command in your startup files.

Comment: @Borodin No, I had tried `export SHELL=/bin/bash` and it did not help.

Comment: @AndrewDwojc: And `env | sort` from bash lists `SHELL`?

Comment: `env | grep SHELL` shows `SHELL=/bin/bash`, however, `perl -e 'warn $INC{SHELL}'` still tells me `Warning: something's wrong at -e line 1`.

Comment: @Borodin: I started a new bash from inside bash the docker gave me and exported SHELL in the new bash (and then perl was giving me a warning). However, when I do `export SHELL=...` in the bash docker gave me then it starts working. So 1) the SHELL variable is set (and visible with bash' `set` command) but not exported (and not shown by bash' `env` command - thanks for mentioning `env`). 2) I still do not understand why it does not work when I do export in the 'nested' bash.

Comment: @AndrewDwojc: Don't get confused between `%ENV` and `@INC`

Comment: @Borodin Argh, silly typo (`INC` vs `ENV`) on top of everything. So you basically solved my mistery. `SHELL` is set but not exported. (And I should have used `env` rather `set` at the bash prompt to verify which variables are exported.)

Comment: What happens if you are not logged in as `root`?

Answer (score 1):

The error message

```
Warning: something's wrong at -e line 1.
```

indicates that the environment variable $SHELL does not exist or **is not exported**.

You can list the exported variables using the `export` command. You can add SHELL to the exported variables using the command:

```
export SHELL
```

Answer (score 1):

Something is wrong with your installation. It looks like the string

> `Warning: something's wrong at -e line 1.`

would only ever be produced by the following code on line 461 in [pp_sys.c](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/305ff1d4a79c10f61723b1d623e63193aa451a01:/pp_sys.c#l461) (that is, when the argument to `warn` is undefined). Therefore, I am going to deduce that something sanitizes the environment before `perl` is invoked. You might also want to examine `root`'s `.profile`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` and other possibly relevant configuration files.

```
 421 PP(pp_warn)
 422 {
 423     dSP; dMARK;
 424     SV *exsv;
 425     STRLEN len;
 426     if (SP - MARK > 1) {
 427         dTARGET;
 428         do_join(TARG, &PL_sv_no, MARK, SP);
 429         exsv = TARG;
 430         SP = MARK + 1;
 431     }
 432     else if (SP == MARK) {
 433         exsv = &PL_sv_no;
 434         EXTEND(SP, 1);
 435         SP = MARK + 1;
 436     }
 437     else {
 438         exsv = TOPs;
 439         if (SvGMAGICAL(exsv)) exsv = sv_mortalcopy(exsv);
 440     }
 441 
 442     if (SvROK(exsv) || (SvPV_const(exsv, len), len)) {
 443         /* well-formed exception supplied */
 444     }
 445     else {
 446       SV * const errsv = ERRSV;
 447       SvGETMAGIC(errsv);
 448       if (SvROK(errsv)) {
 449         if (SvGMAGICAL(errsv)) {
 450             exsv = sv_newmortal();
 451             sv_setsv_nomg(exsv, errsv);
 452         }
 453         else exsv = errsv;
 454       }
 455       else if (SvPOKp(errsv) ? SvCUR(errsv) : SvNIOKp(errsv)) {
 456         exsv = sv_newmortal();
 457         sv_setsv_nomg(exsv, errsv);
 458         sv_catpvs(exsv, "\t...caught");
 459       }
 460       else {
 461         exsv = newSVpvs_flags("Warning: something's wrong", SVs_TEMP); ## <-- Here ...
 462       }
 463     }
 464     if (SvROK(exsv) && !PL_warnhook)
 465          Perl_warn(aTHX_ "%" SVf, SVfARG(exsv));
 466     else warn_sv(exsv);
 467     RETSETYES;
 468 }
```